# Flaky behavior with editingAccessoryType

Tags: ios, uitableview, editing

I am experiencing some flaky behavior with a table view cell's editing accessory type.  I have layed-out a table view controller in storyboard.  There is a parent controller that can show folders and files.  Hitting the "Edit" button creates the editing "+" or "-" for the cells and also adds a detail disclosure editingAccessoryType (as specified in sotryboard).  All is well so far.  Now the flakiness.

In non-editing mode, the user can select select a folder, which pushes another table view controller onto the stack.  In this view, it's possible for the user to move a file from this folder and into the top-level parent view.  When finished, this move seems to work fine, except when the user navigates back to the parent view and selects "Edit", every cell displays the detail disclosure chevron except the just-moved file.  As I said in the previous paragraph, I am not programmatically setting the editingAccessoryType, as it is set for the table in storyboard.  I can toggle Edit/Done as many times as I'd like, same thing.  To make it even more interesting, new files or folders that are added to the parent after the move work when editing.  It is just the moved file.

If I reboot the app, everything is fine when editing.

Any ideas?

--John

Comment: Think I fixed it.  I created a cell identifier for the "add" cell and an identifier for all of the other cells.  In storyboard for the prototype cells, the "add" cell has no editing accessory.